# How to configure endpoint route in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

im new in ASP.NET Core because my basic is from spring framework
So, i confuse to setting up the endpoint in asp.net, so here are some of few of my controller and startup.cs

Controller :

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class StudentController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("GetData")]
```

Startup.cs at app.UseEndpoints():

```
 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

When i try to run the app in my local, and access the endpoint http verb(localhost:5001/api/GetData), it started to show up the error code, so how should i fix this? Should i set up the endpoint route in startup.cs or i dont have to set the endpoint route because in controller i have [HttpPost][ActionName("GetData")]??? Btw, i think i'm using the latest asp.net core (i dont know to check it though), Thanksss

Comment: You can remove [Route] from controller and replace [HttpPost][ActionName(..)] with [HttpPost("api/GetData")]

Comment: thank you, i'll try ur suggestion, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when writing:

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
```

it means that when calling an http call to your base domain with a suffix of this string you can access your controller\method

in this case, you asked for dynamically picking a controller, and dynamically picking an action, this is called "Token replacement in route templates"

when you write `[controller]` or `[action]`
this means that these are taking dynamically in run time
`action` means the method name
and `controller` means the controller name

in your case, you should call
`https://localhost:5001/api/Student/GetData`

more info can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#token-replacement-in-route-templates-controller-action-area

Comment: thank you sir, ur explanation more logical but i'll try it it :)

Comment: Feel free to contact me if you need more help with that